# Connect to Host with VSCode using the private key

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, private-key

I want to connect to a remote server, I know the username and hostname, and I also have the `private_key.pem` file. How can I connect to this virtual machine using VSCode?

I get this error with the solutions on the internet, and that's reasonable because I have not imported this `private_key.pem` file anywhere, and I do not know how.

```
Permission denied (publickey)
```

Thanks for your help.

I use windows, but the remote machine is ubuntu.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can add the private key by following the below steps:

1. Open VSCode
2. Press <kbd>F1</kbd> and search for "Remote-SSH: Open Configuration File"
3. Select the config file to edit and add the new server and private key

   ```
   Host *name-of-ssh-host-here*
   User *your-user-name-on-host*
   HostName *host-fqdn-or-ip-goes-here*
   IdentityFile *C:\\path\\to\\my\\id_rsa*
   ```

   For the `IdentityFile` specify the path of your private key. For Windows make sure to use double slashes.

[Reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_getting-started)

Comment: Specifically, I had a *relative* path to my identity file, not an absolute path like is specified here. This solved my problem.

Comment: where does this `id_rsa` file come from ?

Comment: @D.L generate ssh keys for your system.
ssh-keygen is used to generate the keys for the system

Comment: @JaymitGupta.  But how is this related to the original `private_key.pem` file ?

Comment: @D.L If you have pre-existing (assuming you have already generated it) , you can use that also.

Comment: @it turns out that the path to a google drive `g:\\ ... *.pem` does not work, but a local path `c:\\ ... *.pem` does work

Comment: at first this failed. I had added the key using `ssh-add`  before attempting this approach. after removing that key with `ssh-add -d` this worked.

Comment: On my Windows 10 system, I use `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa` to specify my key.  (VScode recognizes the Linux-style path with no problems...

Answer (score 0):

Some other things to check:

On File explorer, for both:

- `~/.ssh` directory
- `~/.ssh/id_rsa`

remove permissions for everyone except yourself with:

- Properties
- Security
- Edit

And also ensure that `~/.ssh/config` contains:

```
Host myhostname
  HostName myhostname
  User myusername
```

Tested on Windows 10, vscode 1.78.