# Connect to Linux Host from Windows with VSCode using the private key

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh-keys

I have been given a `*.pem` key, which i was able to convert to a `*.ppk` key using putty.

I can connect to the host using putty.

But wanted to do the same using the `remote-ssh` that is offerred in `vs code`.

So append the config file to this:

```
Host my_host
  HostName ip.add.ress.here
  User ubuntu
  IdentityFile full_path_to_ppk_file
```

I then do: remote ssh in vscode and select the host that i set up in the config file (above).

But i get this error:

```
could not establish connection to "ip_addrss".
```

I tried using this helpful link:
[Connect to Host with VSCode using the private key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67969079/connect-to-host-with-vscode-using-the-private-key)

and other similar links.

I also tried other combinations like adding the port.

But none of the combinations work, so now i seem to be guessing"...

So my question is: how can i connect to the linux server using vscode given a ppk file (if this is possible).